# What is the best way to record voice calls on Twilio Proxy Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, twilio, twilio-api

My problem is, we need to record proxy service calls on twillio, and between the 5 possible ways of recording a call, the only one i see as doable, is the in-progress call recording.

The proxy server has 3 webhooks, one of them is the CALLBACK URL. Which is called when someone calls, when the target phone is ringing and lastly when the person hang up the call.

The record request only works if a call is exactly in progress. So when the ringing callback hits my server, i keep pinging the set record url like a blind man, and if in some of them happens to be in-progress, the recordings are set properly. There must be a better way to do this.

If i have to do this way, which cloud service would be proper to do it? Amazon as an example, Step functions? I need to keep calling the api for about a 20 seconds window, until a success response or the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is an example application for controlling calls through Twilio Proxy here: https://github.com/Cfee2000/twilio-proxy-admin-app.

The important part for your question, how to start a recording for an inbound call, can be seen here: https://github.com/Cfee2000/twilio-proxy-admin-app/blob/master/proxyMgrApp.js#L589-L660

The code is in JavaScript and will keep attempting to fetch the call, ensure the call is not yet complete and doesn't already have any recordings, then attempt to start the recording. If starting recording fails, it queues up a new attempt up to a limit.

This is an example written by a Twilion, so is a good way of doing this with no external services.

I can't advise on any cloud services to do this with. I've not tried with a third party service and Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for opinions on things like this. As long as you can perform a retry as in the example code and handle the other cases, you should be fine.

Comment: I feel like pinging a POST request constantly is a bad practice. Am I wrong? Thanks for the advice, I will implement it this way.

Comment: The example code keeps making a GET request until it gets the call in the right state, then makes the POST request to start the recording. I do agree that it’s not the best, but it’s the only way I know of right now.